# MapKit JS. How to obtain file and API key?

Tags: javascript, mapkit

I have found that Apple has a Javascript Maps API. I have been researching and I have got as far as obtaining an Apple ID.

[MapKIT JS - Maps Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/maps/mapkitjs/)

For some reason, when I log in, I cannot see a section where I generate an API key.

[developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com)

Am I missing something or, do I seriously need to actually buy an Apple computer to be able to download a Javascript library?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: It appears that, when it comes to Apple, if you can't find a solution it means it is only available if you buy the product that gives you access to the download through itunes... Sigh. Fair enough.

Comment: I don't how it was back then but today it's pretty simple, this documentation might help: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkitjs/creating_a_maps_identifier_and_a_private_key